# Chrome: Recover document focus after jquery fadeOut

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, focus, fadeout

I'm trying to have an overlay that I can toggle with keyboard keys.
However, once I hide the menu using fade out, the document won't receive my keydown events until I click in the window. How can I make the document receive focus so that it will listen directly after fade out has finished?

```
<div id="overlay" class="overlay">
    <input type="text" value="test"/>    
</div>

$('#overlay').on('keydown', function() {
    $('#overlay').fadeOut(1000);
    return false;
});

$(document).on('keydown', function() {
   $('#overlay').fadeIn(1000);
    return false;
});

.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

[See jsFiddle also](http://jsfiddle.net/darthnimos/vFthq/13/)

Put cursor in input field, press one key.
It should fade out over a second. After that document is not receiving any keydown until I click in it with the mouse. How can I make document receive focus so that I could toggle the modes with just one keyboard key?

Edit: Tested the fiddle in different browsers. This problem seems to be specific for chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove focus from your text field after fading out your overlay

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/vFthq/17)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#overlay').on('keyup', function () {
        $('#overlay').fadeOut(1000);
        $("input[type='text']").blur();
        return false;
    });

    $('body').on('keyup', function () {
        $('#overlay').fadeIn(1000);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That solved the problem!
Weird that setting focus back to document did not undo the input focus.